# Сравнение значений. Непонятный результат

Tags: c#

Прошу объяснить причину неравенства значений, при сравнении оператором ==

```
var table = new System.Data.DataTable("Nodes");
var idColumn = new System.Data.DataColumn("Id")
{
    DataType = typeof(int),
    AutoIncrement = true,
    AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
    AutoIncrementStep = 1
};
table.Columns.Add(idColumn);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    table.Rows.Add(table.NewRow());
}

var tableRow = table.AsEnumerable().Last();

var row = table.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(curRow =>
{
    var x = curRow["Id"];
    var y = tableRow["Id"];
    Console.WriteLine($"Types: {x.GetType()} and {y.GetType()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{x} == {y} is {x == y}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{x} Equals {y} is {x.Equals(y)}");
    Console.WriteLine();
    return x.Equals(y);
});
```

Результат:

```
Types: System.Int32 and System.Int32
1 == 2 is False
1 Equals 2 is False

Types: System.Int32 and System.Int32
2 == 2 is False
2 Equals 2 is True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ты сравниваешь переменные значимого типа, которые упакованы в object.
Сравнение 2-ух переменных ссылочного типа сравнивает равенство ссылок.

В данном случае, они действительно разные. Приведи переменные x и y явно к int и будет ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Точно. Ночной кодинг не всегда продуктивен =)